# ASP.NET Image path issue getting Given Path's format is not supported

Tags: html, css, asp.net, image, path

```
string imgPath = @"\\R:\";
string path1 =  "active\\_test\\PHOTOS\\";
string path2 = "PRE TEST.JPG";
imgPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(imgPath, path1, path2);
```

After combing full path would be \\R:\active\_test\PHOTOS\PRE TEST.JPG

I get full path based on different field values. My requirement is to load image from shared drive and am using handler to display the image.

Forming full path based on path1 and path2. imgPath = @"\R:\" is constant. Loading images from R drive.

```
 System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
```

Above code is throwing Given Path's format is not supported exception. If I copy the fully formed path to browser, browser reformatting the path to
file:///R:/active/_test/PHOTOS/PRE TEST.JPG and  image is loading fine in browser. I know am missing some minor/silly thing. Can't figure out.
Not sure what I am missing here. Can someone please suggest?

Comment: Why are you preceeding the drive letter with a backslash?

Comment: @"\\server\\dev\" + imgname.JPG worked for me in my previous application. When I copy this path to browser I see browser reformatting in similar fashion, file://server/dev/imgname.JPG and image is loading fine. Please suggest if I am missing something.

Comment: typo error: @"\\server\dev\" + imgname.JPG

Comment: It doesn't matter what the browser reformats the URL to, that isn't important. Why are you combining the `@` syntax with double backslashes? the point of using the `@` syntax is that you don't need double backslashes. Just do one or the other.

Comment: I understand how the string literals work but the issue isn't with \\. Added them because I used the similar approach in different application. There is a difference, it was server and now it is shared drive. So we shouldn't have \'s at all before the drive name  Changing string imgPath = @"R:\"; fixed my issue. Thanks Mason for responding quickly.